# Merge two arrays of both values and make as one array like as one key other value in php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two arrays `$arr1` and `$arr2` and want make one array like this $arr.

```
<?php
$arr1 = [0=>'x-api-key',1=>'username',3=>'password'];
$arr2 = [0=>'cb2312b123113b321b',1=>'john',3=>'1234567']; ?>
```

Expected Output:

```
['x-api-key'=>'cb2312b123113b321b','username'=>'john','password'=>'1234567'];
```

Any help?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), which

> Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values

Like so:

```
$result = array_combine($arr1, $arr2)
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [x-api-key] => cb2312b123113b321b
    [username] => john
    [password] => 1234567
)
```

Test the code [here](https://eval.in/936645).